How do I embed a .res file into a PE file?
I'm using the new .NET 9 PersistedAssemblyBuilder to generate some assemblies and I want to embed version information from a .res file. In .NET Framework, I would have used AssemblyBuilder.DefineUnmanagedResource() for that.
I believe the equivalent for .NET 9 is the nativeResources parameter of the constructor of ManagedPEBuilder. The documentation of ResourceSectionBuilder is severely lacking, so I didn't know how it works exactly, but I created this class:
internal class VersionInfoBuilder : ResourceSectionBuilder
{
    public VersionInfoBuilder(string resFilePath)
    {
        if (resFilePath == null)
            return;

        rawBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(resFilePath);
    }

    private readonly byte[] rawBytes = null;

    protected override void Serialize(BlobBuilder builder, SectionLocation location)
    {
        if (rawBytes == null)
            return;

        builder.WriteBytes(rawBytes);
    }
}

I'm using it like this:
public static ManagedPEBuilder CreatePEBuilder(MethodInfo entryPoint, string resFilePath = null)
{
    MetadataBuilder mb = Context.Assembly.GenerateMetadata(out BlobBuilder ilStream, out BlobBuilder mappedFieldData);
    PEHeaderBuilder headerBuilder = new(
        imageBase: 0x00400000,
        imageCharacteristics: Characteristics.ExecutableImage);

    ManagedPEBuilder peBuilder = new(
        headerBuilder,
        new(mb),
        ilStream,
        mappedFieldData,
        entryPoint: MetadataTokens.MethodDefinitionHandle(entryPoint.MetadataToken),
        nativeResources: new VersionInfoBuilder(resFilePath));

    return peBuilder;
}

This doesn't yield the correct results. When I open the generated assembly with 7-Zip, it shows a file called .rsrc, instead of a folder with that name containing a file called version.txt. How do I tell it to use that name?

That is what is supposed to happen.  "folder with that name" is extremely unclear, you can only embed resources, not folders or files.  The ultimate goal is missing from the question, that doesn't help us help you.

Well, when I look into any other .NET assembly containing version info using 7-Zip, the 7-Zip view shows me a folder called ".rsrc" containing a file called "version.txt". I am not sure how that corresponds to the actual structure of the PE file, but it is the way 7-Zip visualizes it. My example produces an assembly that, in 7-Zip, contains a file called ".rsrc". The goal of the question should be clear, I want to be able to see my version information fields in the "Properties" tab of Windows explorer...

OK, that's just the way 7-zip presents it.  Better to use Visual Studio for it, use File > Open > File.  Creating a binary version resource is quite difficult, lots of variable-length strings, good odds that it went wrong.  Consider using the C# compiler to generate the version resource, use attributes.  Example

I have now regenerated the .res file using the C# compiler and when I include it in my assembly with the code above, the fields are still not shown in the file properties. The res files have the same structure in Visual Studio, so the error has to lie somewhere in my code as opposed to the resource file.
